# SQL JOIN based on table contents

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a single table that contains questions with corresponding references to another table and field that contain the answers. Something like:

[image]

I would like to query the questions table and return QID, QuestionText and the value contained in the [ResponseTable].[ResponseField] for each QID. The design seamed flexible at the time. However the app developer is expecting a stored procedure and the SQL developer was counting on an in app solution for this issue.

I am at the end of my rope trying to build this query. How would you suggest accomplishing this task?

Comment: So, you're saying that the query to the response table would vary depending on the question?  What's your reference to know which table to look in? My first thought is that the design should be reviewed.

Comment: The table shown is the master question table that contains almost one hundred questions.  There are 20+ potential table locations (ResponseTable) where the response data could appear and another 20+ potential fields (ResponseField).  The original designer thought it would be easier to manage a set of questions with a reference to where the data lives and dynamically present the Question and Answer data.

Comment: You would probably have to do it with dynamic SQL, which has some major security implications however.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Comment: Are all of the response fields of the same type?  If not then you can not return one query with a different type for for some values of a field than others.  They would have to be converted to all all be of the same type in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you'll like hearing this answer because it will likely mean some major rework, but I think it's the right answer. Get rid of the questions table and put the questions into new Question fields in the Client1, Client9, and Jobs tables; one for each response.

For example the Client1 table will have these fields:

```
ColorPref
ColorPrefQuestion
Rating
RatingQuestion
```

...and so on

Working around that design will be manageable where working around the design you have now will be a headache.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not think this would be possible.  There can be an infinite variation of questions for a given client table because several clients use the same underlying table. I agree, your approach would be ideal if this application was being created from scratch.  I just inherited the mess with the job and am struggling to keep it functional until the next major rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a redesign should be considered (storing all responses in one table, for example), but if that's not a possibility then [dynamic SQL (using `sp_executesql`)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) can be used. However, it can be dangerous to use as it is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). There are some precautions that can be taken, such as using [`QUOTENAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) on table and column names. This is also a good read before using dynamic SQL: [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

```
DECLARE @tableName NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @columnName NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @tableName = 'Client1'
SET @columnName = 'ColorPref'
SET @query = 'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(@columnName) + ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName)

EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have considered the dynamic SQL route and even looked at the referenced article earlier today.  Wouldn't this code still require knowing the columnName and tableName upfront.  I think the theory behind this approach originally was to grab all of the questions and answers for a given question set based on the master table.  I am open to a redesign but given the disperse nature of where the responses live, I don't know another good alternative.  Where the data lives is so entrenched that that part will likely never change.

Comment: SQL injection's probably not an issue since the query isn't using any externally-supplied input, just data already in the tables.

Comment: @Quark No, the data does not have to be known up front. This is just an example. The values of `@tableName` and `@columnName` could come from anywhere. In your case I assume you'd `SELECT` them from the questions table based on QID.

Comment: @TMN True, but always worth mentioning. And, if `ResponseField` can somehow be populated by user input, SQL injection is conceivable.

Answer (score 0):

Until you get to the rewrite you mentioned, consider the idea of using a view to bring these response tables together.

```
CREATE VIEW ClientResponses AS
    SELECT QID, ResponseField FROM [Client1]
    UNION
    SELECT QID, ResponseField FROM [Jobs]
    UNION
    SELECT QID, ResponseField FROM [Client9]
    -- ..... add the new tables as they are created
```

This will

1. Avoid dynamic SQL
2. Give you a single place to maintain querying
3. Provide a pretty simple, readable way to hobble this together